# How to connect Java program to docker-compose

Tags: java, linux, api, docker-compose

I wrote java program that sends POST and GET requests to docker (using docker remote API).

Now I want to write a java program that can get a `docker-compose.yml` and run it.

my docker version is: 1.11.2

my docker-compose version is: 1.9.0

I'm working on Linux using MobaXterm.

How to do this?

Comment: OK, where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is a tool to expose RESTful APIs to control docker-compose:

https://github.com/francescou/docker-compose-ui

From the site:

> The aim of this project is to provide a minimal HTTP API on top of Docker Compose while maintaining full interoperability with Docker Compose CLI.
>
> The application can be deployed as a single container, there are no dependencies nor databases to install.

Here are the API Docs:
https://francescou.github.io/docker-compose-ui/api.html

---

This should allow you to write a similar tool to the one you wrote to communicate with docker's remote API.